# HTTP version for CURL command on server and docker image

Tags: rhel, docker, curl, http

When I'm doing a CURL call `curl https://example.com` from a docker container, I got the error `curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED (err 13)`. But when I'm running the same command from the host server (RHEL) where docker container is running, it is working fine.

So, I have added --http1.1 to the command in docker container, then it is working fine. But when I run the same command with --http1.1 on host server, then I got error `curl: option --http1.1: is unknown`.

1. How the curl picks up the http version while making the call? Is there any setting that we can define to use a specific version by default?
2. Why --http1.1 is not working on server, but working in docker container?

Curl version on server is 7.29.0. Curl version on docker container is 7.64.0

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Fix your webserver.

**Long story**

Your HTTP server must be doing something "wrong"! `curl` will not attempt to do a  HTTP/2 connection unless the server advises that it can do it.

So, the answer to the questions are:

> How the curl picks up the http version while making the call?

It listens to what the server claims to support.

> Is there any setting that we can define to use a specific version by default?

Yes, that's built in to the HTTP protocol (first line of response); actually, considering you're using TLS (`http`**`s`**`://…`),  this should already be clearly defined by client using the `h2` protocol identifier in TLS/ALPN, and the server will respond that it supports the `h2` protocol, i.e. it agrees that it can indeed talk HTTP/2.

Otherwise, `curl` will **not** use HTTP/2.

You can check your HTTP server's misbehaviour yourself!

```bash
$ # https://stackoverflow.com does support HTTP/2
$ curl --verbose --output /dev/null https://stackoverflow.com
…
* Connected to stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
…
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
…
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
…
> GET / HTTP/2
```

So, here you can see, `curl` offers  `h2` as protocol ID to the server, and the server actually has to accept that before `curl` uses HTTP/2.

Compare that with what an outdated webserver does, and how `curl` reacts:

```bash
$ # https://www.gnu.org only supports HTTP/1.1, in 2023.
$ curl --verbose --output /dev/null https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/normal.html
* Connected to www.gnu.org (2001:470:142:5::116) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
…
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
…
> GET /software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/normal.html HTTP/1.1
```

So, your web server must be telling `curl` in the TLS connection establishment that it supports HTTP/2 (by signalling `h2` support), but then actually not support it.

> Why --http1.1 is not working on server, but working in docker container?

Your host server's `curl` is **very** old; that option was added in curl version 7.33.0, which was nearly 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The server is accepting the h2 and curl is selecting h2 as you mentioned. Is this a docker image issue? Or server issue? If this is a docker issue, how can we fix this?

I see below log when I ran curl -Iv <url>.

```Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!```
```HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED (err 13)```

Comment: Server issue, as said in the first line.